# Referencing jars from other projects in the build path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, build, jar

I have placed a series of jars in a single eclipse project.
I.e. I have a separate eclipse project (named e.g. `JARS-Project`) that has in its build path a whole bunch of jars .
From another eclipse project e.g. `ProjectX` I add a reference to the `JARS-Project` in the build path.
Problem:
I can not seem to be able to use any of the libraries in `JARS-Project` from `ProjectX`.
I was expecting to be able to use all the libraries in the buildpath of `JARS-Project` from the `ProjectX` since it references it in the build path.
I can not see what other configuration I might have missed.
Don't think it makes a different but `ProjectX` was created as a Spring Project

Comment: Do they show up in your "Referenced Libraries" when in the "Package Explorer" view?

Comment: The jars appear as "Referenced Libraries" within the "Package Explorer" view only in the `JARS-Project`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not referencing the jars in `JARS-Project` from `ProjectX`, you are referencing `JARS-Project` from `ProjectX`, which is different.

To reference the jars in `JARS-Project` from `ProjectX`, you have to reference each jar individually. So go to your build path for `ProjectX`, then go to Libraries tab, then press "Add Jars", then find each jar you need from the `JARS-Project` project and add individually.

**Note**, for this to work the jar files themselves must be in the `JARS-Project` project. If `JARS-Project` only references the jars from elsewhere in the file system this will not work.

Comment: If I do it as you say, when I press "Add Jars" the popup for Jar Selection appears showing the `JARS-Project` and `ProjectX` but there is no option to choose the jars of `JARS-Project`.I.e. the jars of `JARS-Project` do not appear for selection

Comment: Are the jars actually stored as files within the JARS-Project project? Or are they referenced from elsewhere in your file system? If the latter, then you won't be able to reference them in this way. You would have to copy the jars into the JARS-Project project.

Comment: Yes..My bad.Modify your answer to mention to copy the jars inside the `JARS-Project` instead of referencing them in external directories and I will accept it

Comment: Sure thing. Done. For an alternate look at dependency management, you may want to give Maven a look.